# Invoke JUnit tests using TestNG

Tags: java, junit, testng

Is there anyway to invoke JUnit tests using TestNG? I tried using

```
<test name="JunitTest" preserve-order="true" junit="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.*****.testautomation.AllTests"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Where AllTests is JUnit TestSuite.

It gives me following error

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Failure in JUnit mode for class com.*****.testautomation.AllTests: could not create/run JUnit test suite: 
Cannot find JUnit method class junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning
    at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.runFailed(JUnitTestRunner.java:237)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.start(JUnitTestRunner.java:230)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:211)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:672)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1003)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:703)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
```

Comment: JUnit still has to be on the TestNG classpath http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html

Comment: This problem was affecting me as well (TestNG 6.3.1, JUnit 4.10, even with JUnit properly in the classpath). After some digging I found a claim that only JUnit 3 is supported, but the docs say otherwise. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-dev/uERCJvdHEpw and http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  I changed junit='true' to false and testng didn't try to run in junit compatiblity mode.

```
  <test name="Junit tests" junit="false">
```